# Mutliple buttons on one html page returning the same function- flask python

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

For a changing quantity in a cart.html page I have 3 seperate buttons for remove, increase and decrease the quantity. However, every time I press a button it only runs the increase function even though they all have different urls? enter code here

```
<td class="action" >
                                    <form class="form" action="{{ url_for('increaseQuantity') }}" method="post">
                                        <button class="ti-plus"  value="{{ cart.Products.productID }}" name ="productID" ></button>
                                    </form>
                               </td>
                                <td class="qty" data-title="Qty"><!-- Input Order -->
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text"  class="input-number" value="{{ cart.Cart.quantity }}">
                                    </div>
                                   
                                </td>
                                <td class="action" >
                                    <form class="form" action="{{ url_for('minusQuantity') }}" method="post">
                                        <button class="ti-minus"  value="{{ cart.Products.productID }}" name ="productID" ></button>
                                    </form>
                               </td>
                                
                                <td class="action" data-title="Remove">
                                <form class="form" action="{{ url_for('removeFromCart') }}" method="post">
                                    <button class="ti-trash remove-icon"  value="{{ cart.Products.productID }}" name ="productID" ></button>
                                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `name` attribute on your buttons they are all having same `name`.

Answer (score 0):

This HTML snippet is not enough to help you. Try looking at the generated code using you browser's tools, or add the URL dictionnary.

Also, you need to submit a form, with an input/button of the "submit" type. Their absence may create errors.

From https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp :

> Tip: Always specify the type attribute for a  element, to tell browsers what type of button it is.